# I want to get a JSON file from API and display it in the Interface using axios, but the problem is that I got always nothing n the interface

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, vue.js

I'm sorry I did a mistake in my previos question...

I want to get a JSON file from API and display it in the Interface using axios ,but it doesn't work !I mean the interface doesn't show anything ; it must show the JSON value

so the API link is : "http://localhost:8080/route" and the JSON file when I go to this link is :

```
[{"carspeed":"I'm here"}]
```

My interface (which is runing at http://localhost:8081 )code is :

```
  <template> 
  .
  .
 <v-btn x-large color="grey"  class="d-flex align-start flex-column mb-6" 
 @click="getspeed" 
 >Start</v-btn>
    </v-row>

  <div v-if="todos">
    <li>{{todos}}</li>
  </div>
 </template>
```

followed by :

```
import axios from 'axios';
const WorkersURL="http://localhost:8080/route";

export default {
 data: () => ({
 drawer: false,
 todos:

  }),  
 methods: {
  async getspeed() {

  axios.get(WorkersURL)
  .then(response => {
   this.todos = response.data
   })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors = e
  })

 }
```

Where is the issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What has changed since the last question you asked on the same subject (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065129/i-want-to-get-a-json-file-from-api-and-display-it-in-the-interface-using-axios)?

Comment: I updated the message ,I want to learn how to display a simple message,then how to display an array

Comment: is very hard to tell where the error is with code that run for you in localhost, we can´t test, etc. 
But if axios is throwing an error you are setting this.errors and you are not showing in the view. So try doing 
this.errors = e;
console.log(e) 

Also you can console.log(response) in the axios promise then(response => {console.log(response) ;this.todos = response.data})  so in case your request is returning data you can see the response structure (if its a 200 code type, its a successfull call and you may see the body of the response).

Comment: I don't have any error , it just dosen't displaying the value in the interface ... I just did what you told me , I didn't get anything as response in console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to get a JSON file from API and display it in the Interface using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065129/i-want-to-get-a-json-file-from-api-and-display-it-in-the-interface-using-axios)

Comment: No :(  the same problem

Comment: What do You see in console.log(response.data) or just console.log(response)? BTW - Why are You using "async" but not "await" later? Remove async or if you wanna keep it async just use "return" because axios returns promise.